# Can anyone tell me what type of fish this is?

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology, ichthyology

Notice the reflective patterns on its underside.  I think it must be a deep water fish.  It was found washed up on the ocean sand in Myrtle Beach, South Carolina (USA) after a hurricane.
[image: Here is a picture of it]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not an expert, but an online search for bioluminscent fish led me to a bioluminescent toadfish called [***Porichthys porosissimus***](http://www.fishbase.us/FieldGuide/FieldGuideSummary.php?genusname=Porichthys&speciesname=porosissimus&c_code=076). The ventral angle of your specimen looks a lot like the photos I could find...

[image]

<sup>Source: Robertson, R on [Fishbase](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRm-HY6bKgfCSSm-AM4ETIQ_eiNqIYe1w8W6Kl0ckHP64dA3u1a)</sup>

Like many [midshipman fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midshipman_fish), *P. porosissimus* have [photophores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photophore) (those dots in your specimen) that glow to attract prey:

[image]

<sup>Source: W. Ward ([Rutgers Center for Research and Education in Bioluminescence and Biotechnology](http://www-rci.rutgers.edu/~crebb/Toadfish.htm))</sup>

Comment: [This site](https://www.discoverlife.org/mp/20q?search=Porichthys+porosissimus) provides a sightings map, but some of the points are sort of suspect, so I don't know how accurate it is...